# Android Marshmallow Permissions Tests

Tags: android, unit-testing, testing, permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow

I came across this issue in our team: We want to test interactions with the calendar and we obviously need calendar write permission in order to do this.
Is there a way to make sure necessary permissions are in place for instrument tests? I know you can virtually grant permissions on a specific avd but is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 2):

You can grant and revoke permissions using:

```
adb pm grant com.package.myapp android.permission.<PERMISSION>
adb pm revoke com.package.myapp android.permission.<PERMISSION>
```

Update for Android Debug Bridge (adb) version 1.0.32:

You need to add shell to run these commands, e.g. ./adb shell pm grant ......

Answer (score 0):

I would comment but I can't yet,
here a guide on android M permissions: http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/things-you-need-to-know-about-android-m-permission-developer-edition/en.

 In android M you need to check 2 things before doing something that requires permissions. 1. If they allowed or denied 2. If they chose deny always or not (remember my choice). 
 Most of this is covered in the link I provided. 
I don't know if you can apply this to tests but I would think so.

Comment: Thank for your reply. Thing is I am running the tests on a remote machine in my CI server (on Jenkins to be exact). Now it's a hassle if I want to manually accept or reject a certain permission for a new test that potentially uses a certain permission. Moreover, these are run on an AVD not a real device. So I am not sure if just checking for the permissions would do the trick.